# Звуковое оповещение о неактивности поля для ввода текста

Tags: работа-с-текстом

Бывает так, что начинаешь ввод текста в комментариях к какому-либо посту (не глядя на монитор) и после набора одного или нескольких абзацев видишь, что набранный текст в поле ввода не появился, т.к. само поле ввода не было активно при начале набора. 
Можно-ли настроить компьютер так, чтобы при таком наборе текста компьютер подавал звуковой сигнал оповещения о неактивном состоянии поля для ввода текста?

Comment: Самый лучший сигнал, это смотреть на экран, когда что-либо пишешь. Необходимо стараться учиться писать не глядя на клавиатуру. :)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд компьютер никак не настроишь под подобную задачу. Возможен вариант использования какого-либо приложения или дополнения для используемого Вами браузера, но тоже не факт что найдется.

Лучший способ:

1. Смотреть на экран перед набором текста.
2. Научиться набирать текст не смотря на клавиатуру (благо есть много тренажеров на любой вкус).
3. Если используете ноутбук, то сможет частично помочь отключение тачпада (сам иногда случайно зацеплю его и уже активен другой объект).